# How avoid error when downloading data from url in R?

Tags: html, r, url

Last week i could download data using this code

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

url<-paste("https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/4a90f2/globalassets/marketdata-excel-files/elspot-prices_2020_hourly_eur.xls")
df.np2 <- readHTMLTable(htmlTreeParse(getURL(url), useInternalNodes=TRUE))[[1]]
```

However, I tried to do it now, and got the following error

```
Error in readHTMLTable(htmlTreeParse(getURL(url), useInternalNodes = TRUE))[[1]] : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

Do you know where am I made mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what you want to read has moved to another direction.

```
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/4a9d52/globalassets/marketdata-excel-files/elspot-prices_2020_hourly_eur.xls">here</a>.</h2>
```

Comment: It is what "getURL(url)"  returns.